# How to redirect programmatically to exception error page?

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-ee

How do I redirect to the error page defined in `web.xml` programmatically?

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

How do I get `/error.xhtml` through `FacesContext`?

Sometimes exceptions can occur in overriden methods and there I cannot throw a occuring exception and need to manually handle the exception e.g redirect to the error page myself.

Comment: If you say so, i don't know. But that link helps in no way, i already have my custom exception error page which works fine. I need to get the url of the error site to redirect to it.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get an error page value from web.xml like this. Any place where you can manually send a redirect you should be able to instead throw the exception needed to show the error page defined in web.xml. If you mean the overridden methods are throwing a different type of exception than the error page needs, you can catch that exception and then throw the exception you want instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be retrieved using the Omnifaces library.

From the documentation:

`This configuration enum parses the /WEB-INF/web.xml and all /META-INF/web-fragment files found in the classpath and offers methods to obtain information from them which is not available by the standard Servlet API.`

http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/WebXml